# perform random draw with uneven stakes without loop?

Tags: algorithm, loops

The following is pseudo-code.

float totalStakes = 0;
float[] participantStakes[];

```
int EnterDraw(float _stakes) {
    totalStakes += _stakes;
    participantStakes.push(_stakes);
    return participantStakes.length - 1;
}

int SelectWinner() {
    float rnd = Random(0, totalStakes);
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<participantStakes.length; i++) {
        sum += participantStakes[i];
        if (rnd <= sum) {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

bool DidIWin(int _participantID) {
    return (SelectWinner() == i);
}
```

This pseudocode runs a raffle where participants have different winning probabilities.
My question is if there is any way to implement this without having to potentially iterate over all elements?

important: the random number is generated only after all participants entered the draw.

Comment: No, there isn't. You can't perform a draw without knowing the value of `totalStakes`, and you can't calculate `totalStakes` without iterating over every draw entry.

Comment: Does DidIWin calculate a new winner every time? It only needs to run once

Comment: individual calls to EnterDraw I do not regard as a loop in this case. I wonder if I can do anything in the individual EnterDraw calls to setup the final draw such that it can be performed without a loop.

Comment: If you have a second array with accumulated stakes that you also push on EnterDraw, you can later use binary search on SelectWinner

Comment: @juvian so that means I probably would need to have a binary search tree that I'd fill in the EnterDraw calls. That would make EnterDraw O(log n) and SelectWinner O(log n) as well, is that correct?

Comment: EnterDraw would still be O(1), and SelectWinner O(log n). Just need an array, no binary tree

Comment: @juvian for SelectWinner to be O(log n), the entries must be sorted by size, and insertion into a sorted list can't be O(1), can it?

Comment: You already insert them in sorted order so no need to sort. check daniel answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that you can't avoid looping through the array if you just store the count of stakes and I based my answer on @juvian's comment.

Instead of storing the number of stakes in an array I stored the range of indexes for each participant.  This way there is no dependency on the values in other elements of the array.  From there a binary search is conducted to find the winning index.

One tweak in the search is that it starts from a position relative to the winning stake's value to total stakes instead of the absolute mid point.  So this should perform better in with normally distributed set of data.

```
int EnterDraw(float _stakes) {
    totalStakes += _stakes;
    min = (pStakes.length > 0) ? pStakes[pStakes.length - 1].cutoff : 0;
    cutoff = min + _stakes;
    pStakes.push({ min, cutoff });
    return pStakes.length - 1;
}

int SelectWinner() {
    float rnd = Random(0, totalStakes);
    int i = floor(pStakes.length * rnd / totalStakes);
    int high = totalStakes - 1;
    int low = 0;
    while (!(pStakes[i].min <= rnd && pStakes[i].max > rnd) {
      if (pStakes[i].min > rnd) {
        high = i - 1;
        i = floor((i - low) / 2) + low;
      }
      else {
        low = i + 1;
        i = floor((high - i) / 2) + low;
      }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Storing cutoff is enough, will just need to handle index = 0 case in SelectWinner without min

Comment: @juvian post that in your answer.  I already got the idea for my answer from your comment and I hate taking credit for someone else's good ideas.

Comment: Thats okay, busy to do a full answer ^^